# How to add auto-completion for ZSH to any type of script without writing files and changing .zshrc?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, autocomplete

I have a large codebase that will get cloned by every user to his own system before using it on a large HPC-cluster, where I do not have root-priviledges.
Some of the scripts are perl-, python- and bash-scripts and I'd love to add auto-completion for ZSH for them.

But I cannot re-write the .zshrc to add completetion files, because the repo might be cloned several times and only live on for a short period of time before they get removed automatically. This would greatly clutter the .zshrc-file.
Is there anything I can do to add auto-completetion from within the directory only, without reloading the shell?
Let's say my script is `sbatch.pl` and has the options `--help` and `--debug` and `--project=NAME_OF_THE_PROJECT`.

Can I somehow create a `._sbatch.pl.zsh_autocompletion` file that ZSH reads automatically when doing `perl sbatch.pl <TAB>` without ever writing anything in any other directory or altering any local user files?

Answer (score 0):

You can add completion for commands at runtime like this:

```bsh
# First tell zsh where to find the function.
autoload -Uz /absolute/path/to/_sbatch.pl 

# Then tell the completion system to use _sbatch.pl to complete for sbatch.pl
compdef _sbatch.pl sbatch.pl
```

It's trivial enough to put a script in the root of your repo that runs these commands. Then all you need to do is source the script to enable the completions.

Heck, if you give each of these scripts the exact same path in each repo, say, `.sh/zsh`, then you can even run them automatically, by adding this to your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook chpwd .sh-zsh
.sh-zsh() {
  local repo
  repo="$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null )" ||
      return
  [[ -r $repo/.sh/zsh ]] &&
      source $repo/.sh/zsh
}
```

Whenever you enter a dir that is anywhere inside a Git repo, this will source the file `<repo root>/.sh/zsh`.

(I chose to use a directory for this, rather than putting a file in the root of the repo, so you can add support files for other shells in the same dir.)

---

Tip: To determine the absolute path to the dir containing your script from within the script itself, use `${${(%):-%x}:a:h}`. For more info, see:

- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers
- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags
- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state